# Not able to search a query using find methon properly in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

Here I am trying to find all those documents having searched string in cui_str of either population_mesh or intervention_mesh or outcome_mesh

I am using $or property to find from three different fields. I am using below query from nodejs to fetch from mongodb.

```
exports.searchQuery= (req,res) => {
     const picoSearch = req.query.text

  Pico_tests.find({$or : [{"population_mesh.cui_str" : {$regex: `${picoSearch}`,$options: '$i'}},{"intervention_mesh.cui_str" : {$regex: `${picoSearch}`,$options: '$i'}},
    {"outcomes_mesh.cui_str" : {$regex: `${picoSearch}`,$options: '$i'}}]}).then((data)=>{
        res.send(data)        
    })

// Here i am searching in three different fields but is fetching all the documents irrespective of any string searched.
}
```

**But in the result I am getting all the documents rather than specific documents containing that string.** I have check a lot of time in database that given string(i.e Patient) searched but I got all the documents rather than specific one.

Comment: please add sample input and your desired output and also the schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very silly mistake of spell which make all docs get fetched.